# Separate function could not be found

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, rscript

```r
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

id <- c(1:10)
  
name <- c("John Mendes", "Rob Stewart", "Rachel Abrahamson", "Christy Hickman", "Johnson Harper", "Candace Miller", "Carlson Landy", "Pansy Jordan", "Darius Berry", "Claudia Garcia")
  
job_title <- c("Professional", "Programmer", "Management", "Clerical", "Developer", "Programmer", "Management", "Clerical", "Developer", "Programmer")
  
employee <- data.frame(id, name, job_title)

separate(employee, name,into=c('first_name','last_name'),sep=' ')
```

Comment: Presumably that's the `separate` function from `tidyr`, which you'd need to load with `library(tidyr)` or `library(tidyverse)`.

Comment: @JonSpring, seems a little silly, but you might as well post that as the answer.